# error 1004 ? if else reasonable to use

Tags: vba, if-statement, match

After working on this for a few hours and searching the forums, I haven't found a great solution for the following problem just yet.

I have a macro-enabled worksheet running in excel 2016. I have four sheets "Orders", "Intake", "Hard Data", "Office Visit".

I have created a userform which has a command button (CommandButtonAbsorbIntakeData). I have pasted the code below in the hopes that someone can spot any issues I have that would produce a error 1004. I understand the error to indicate there is no Match found. I am using an if else statement as a trigger since the match function returns a value. If the value is greater that or equal to 1, a piece of code will run. If it is anything other than that, another code will run.
My issue is that when a match IS NOT found, my else code does not run. Is if else not a good option with match? Thanks for any feedback.

```
    Option Explicit
    Public Sub CommandButtonAbsorbIntakeData_Click()
    Dim lrowintakes As Variant
    Dim patient As Variant
    Dim myworksheet As Worksheet
    Dim myworksheet2 As Worksheet
    Dim myworksheet3 As Worksheet
    Dim myfirstblankrow As Variant
    Dim patientexistence As Variant


    patient = Me.TextBoxIntakeName.Value & " " &  Me.TextBoxIntakeDateOfBirth.Value

    lrowintakes = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(patient, Sheets("Hard Data").Range("A1:A200"), 0)

           If lrowintakes >= 1 Then
        Set myworksheet = Worksheets("Hard Data")
            With myworksheet
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 1) = Me.TextBoxIntakeName.Value & " " & Me.TextBoxIntakeDateOfBirth.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 2) = Me.TextBoxIntakeName.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 3) = Me.TextBoxIntakeDateOfBirth.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 14) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMeds1.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 15) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMeds2.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 16) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMeds3.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 17) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMeds4.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 18) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMeds5.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 19) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMeds6.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 20) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMeds7.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 21) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMeds8.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 22) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMeds9.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 23) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMedicalProblems1.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 24) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMedicalProblems2.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 25) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMedicalProblems3.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 26) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMedicalProblems4.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 27) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMedicalProblems5.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 28) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMedicalProblems6.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 29) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMedicalProblems7.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 30) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMedicalProblems8.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 31) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMedicalProblems9.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 32) = Me.TextBoxIntakeSurgeries1.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 33) = Me.TextBoxIntakeSurgeries2.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 34) = Me.TextBoxIntakeSurgeries3.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 35) = Me.TextBoxIntakeSurgeries4.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 36) = Me.TextBoxIntakeSurgeries5.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 37) = Me.TextBoxIntakeSurgeries6.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 38) = Me.TextBoxIntakeSurgeries7.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 39) = Me.TextBoxIntakeSurgeries8.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 40) = Me.TextBoxIntakeSurgeries9.Value
                .Cells(lrowintakes, 41) = Me.TextBoxIntakeFamilyHistory
            End With

    Else
    'add information in next available row in Hard Data Sheet, concatenates name and DOB for datatag column
        Set myworksheet = Worksheets("Hard Data")
        With myworksheet
            myfirstblankrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 1) = Me.TextBoxIntakeName.Value & " " & Me.TextBoxIntakeDateOfBirth.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 2) = Me.TextBoxIntakeName.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 3) = Me.TextBoxIntakeDateOfBirth.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 14) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMeds1.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 15) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMeds2.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 16) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMeds3.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 17) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMeds4.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 18) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMeds5.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 19) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMeds6.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 20) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMeds7.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 21) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMeds8.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 22) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMeds9.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 23) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMedicalProblems1.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 24) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMedicalProblems2.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 25) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMedicalProblems3.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 26) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMedicalProblems4.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 27) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMedicalProblems5.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 28) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMedicalProblems6.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 29) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMedicalProblems7.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 30) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMedicalProblems8.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 31) = Me.TextBoxIntakeMedicalProblems9.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 32) = Me.TextBoxIntakeSurgeries1.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 33) = Me.TextBoxIntakeSurgeries2.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 34) = Me.TextBoxIntakeSurgeries3.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 35) = Me.TextBoxIntakeSurgeries4.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 36) = Me.TextBoxIntakeSurgeries5.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 37) = Me.TextBoxIntakeSurgeries6.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 38) = Me.TextBoxIntakeSurgeries7.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 39) = Me.TextBoxIntakeSurgeries8.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 40) = Me.TextBoxIntakeSurgeries9.Value
            .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 41) = Me.TextBoxIntakeFamilyHistory.Value
        End With
        'add datatag to OFFICE VISITS
        Set myworksheet2 = Worksheets("Office Visits")
            With myworksheet2
                myfirstblankrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
                .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 1).Value = Me.TextBoxIntakeName & " " & Me.TextBoxIntakeDateOfBirth
            End With
        'add datatag to ORDERS
        Set myworksheet3 = Worksheets("Orders")
            With myworksheet3
                myfirstblankrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
                .Cells(myfirstblankrow, 1).Value = Me.TextBoxIntakeName & " " & Me.TextBoxIntakeDateOfBirth
            End With

    End If


    End Sub
```

Comment: This helped address the issue! Thank you @Comintern . used the Iferror method and removed the "WorksheetFunctions" portion of calling the Match application.

Answer (score 0):

The method I've always used for things like this is the find method.

An example of how to start your code would start:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CommandButtonAbsorbIntakeData_Click()
Dim lrowintakes As Variant
Dim patient As Variant
Dim myworksheet As Worksheet
Dim myworksheet2 As Worksheet
Dim myworksheet3 As Worksheet
Dim myfirstblankrow As Variant
Dim patientexistence As Variant
Dim KeyRange As Range

Worksheets("Hard Data").Select

patient = Me.TextBoxIntakeName.Value & " " & Me.TextBoxIntakeDateOfBirth.Value

Set KeyRange = Worksheets("Hard Data").Range("A1:A200").Find(patient, Range("A1"), xlValues, xlWhole, xlRows, xlNext)
If Not KeyRange Is Nothing Then 'If "patient" was found then
```

From here you would just need to fill in the rest of your code! I like this method because it gives you an easy visual way to deal with the code if your value isn't found in the sheet. Hope this helped!